# C# Unit Testing with TestInitialize/TestCleanup in base class

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I am testing a module where every test class share the same behavior:

- Begin a transaction
- Execute SQL queries
- Rollback transaction

I've decided to use TestInitialize and TestCleanup to execute the Begin and Rollback of transactions respectively.

The strait forward approach would be writing the TestInitialize/TestCleanup in a parent class but that is not going to work with this testing framework.

The **work around** for this was to use **partial classes**. This approach seems to viable in my case because my test classes are mainly stateless. Event not being the ideal solution it at least saved me a couple of copy/paste actions.

Anyone knows a better way to do this?

Here is a sample of the **partial class** solution:

In my case I test each module separately and for this example I will use the **Sales** module:

**SalesTest.cs file**:

```
[TestClass]
public partial class SalesTest
{
    [TestInitialize]
    public void Setup()
    {
        //begin transaction
    }

    [TestCleanup]
    public void Cleanup()
    {
        //rollback transaction
    }
}
```

**SalesTest.Order file**:

```
public partial class SalesTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void SaveOrder_OnlyRequiredValuesFilled_SuccessfullySaved()
    {
        //Run some SQL queries 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Looks like you're using `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting` framework. I don't see any problem using a base class for Cleanup and Initialize.

E.g.

```
   [TestClass]
    public class TestDemo : BaseTests
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void SaveOrder_OnlyRequiredValuesFilled_SuccessfullySaved()
        {
            //Run some SQL queries 
        }

    }

    [TestClass]
    public abstract class BaseTests
    {
        [TestInitialize]
        public void Setup()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Setup executed.");
            //begin transaction
        }

        [TestCleanup]
        public void Cleanup()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Cleanup executed.");
            //rollback transaction
        }
    }
```

This will work fine and I can inherit the `BaseTest` to any Test and the Intiailize and Cleanup will execute before and after any test.

Comment: FYI: It only worked for me when I added `[TestClass]`, `[TestInitialize]`, and `[TestCleanup]` to all the base classes and their methods.

Comment: A common mistake is also to call your method Cleanup in both the base class and the current class. That prevents both cleanups from running, and will run only the cleanup in the inherited class (because the base Cleanup is hidden by the new Cleanup method).

Comment: Even if the methods have different names, but both have the `[TestInitialize()]` decorator?

Comment: @HannesZiegler I'm not sure if it's allowed. There can only be one initialize and one clean up in each class. Though you can override these in child class.